# Monit memory utilization different from Ubuntu's own diagnostics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vps, linode, monit

I have a Linode 512 VPS running Ubuntu 12.04 and I noticed a very big discrepency between Monit's report of memory utilization and Ubuntu's report.  This becomes an issue when monit tries to restart some of my processes when it crosses a certain threshold.  Does anyone know why there is this discrepency?

[image: Ubuntu]

[image: Monit]

Comment: You should try **newrelic** ( http://newrelic.com/ ) to monitor your servers

Comment: What's the first output from?  Try `top`, or for just memory `free` -- there are different states of memory use that monit may be aggregating.

Comment: i recently switched off newrelic because I heard monit has a better memory footprint.

Comment: @tharrison the top image is from ubuntu's own system information summary when you ssh into the server.

Comment: NewRelic is indeed brilliant, and especially perfect for Rails.  Its memory footprint is very small; if larger than monit, then only by a tiny amount.  I am not sure what generates the system information when you log in, but if you need to know about memory, `free` and `top` are the right tools to use.  If they do not reconcile with monit (or NewRelic) then something odd is going on.  There may be cache or other buffers that are not being counted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without digging too deep into monit's source code, it appears that monit takes into account memory buffers used by the kernel when computing used memory.

From monit on my Linode:

```
  status                            Running
  monitoring status                 Monitored
  load average                      [0.00] [0.01] [0.05]
  cpu                               0.0%us 0.0%sy 0.0%wa
  memory usage                      264652 kB [52.0%]
  swap usage                        47096 kB [2.2%]
  data collected                    Tue, 11 Dec 2012 20:51:45
```

and running `free` right after:

```
               total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
  Mem:        508576     405572     103004          0      20288     120636
  -/+ buffers/cache:     264648     243928
  Swap:      2097148      47092    2050056
```

Considering monit's default configuration is to refresh every 120 seconds, 264648 kB pretty accurate compared to monit's 264652 kB.